# Find out what thread opened fd

Tags: c++, c, linux, file-descriptor

I've been searching for a solution on Linux to find out what thread first aquired a fd but no luck for now.

```
/proc/pid/task/
```

shows the fd to be available to each thread, which makes sense since descriptors are available troughout the whole process space.

```
lsof
```

is of course not of much help either for this usecase.

The program is very complex, and strace or gdb won't help either, there are tons of closed source libraries  used. File path is known but does not help since I don't have access to the code in the libaries. I suspect the fd leak is due to some race condition that occurrs very very rarely and I need to trace the thread that did opened the file.

One solution that would be  easy to implement would be for me to add a log in the kernel file open handler or in the c library, but for good reasons I'm not able to alter nor the kernel neither the standard library.

Some suggestions?

Comment: @tobi303 add it where? I don't have access to the source of the library that does this, I don't know what library does it, I can't change the kernel nor the c library. That's why I need to find out the thread id, as it's not my thread.

Comment: It is not my thread doing this, it's from some library that I don't have access to code for.

Comment: ah ok, sorry for the spam ;)

Comment: As you don't want to write/modify the kernel code, why do you use "linux-kernel" tag?

Comment: @Tsyvarev maybe there's something already in the kernel that provides that and I'm not aware of, although chances are slim. It's not that I don't want to modify it, I can't, it's a production unit and this can only be done at the other end of the world, with lots of paper work - takes somehwere around 3-4 months.

Comment: If there is something that kernel provides for user space, then this is a "linux" feature, not a "linux-kernel" one. [Pseudo filesytems `/sys`, `/proc`, etc. are "linux" features.] I see the last reason for "linux-kernel" tag here: you are allowed to write your own kernel modules and insert them into the kernel. E.g., in @George McCollister [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47353087/3440745) an additional module is automatically created by SystemTap. If you doesn't treat kernel modules even as a *possible* tool for your task, then I see no reason for "linux-kernel" tag.

Comment: Indeed, George's answer is exactly what I needed but I'll just remove the kernel tag since never occured to me that a simple tag may cause such an inconvenience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have kernel symbols available use SystemTap:

`sudo stap -e 'probe syscall.open.return { \
               printf("tid=%d, fd=%d\n", tid(), $return) }'`